# Alerting dropdown options on change

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to save off the form value of a select dropdown list on change?

**HTML**

```
<select class="form_select" id="typeof_dwelling" name="typeof_dwelling">
  <option value="-1">All </option>
  <option value="APTU">Condos</option>
  <option value="HOUSE">Houses</option> 
  <option value="TWNHS">Townhouses</option>
  <option value="LOFTS">Lofts</option> 
  <option value="LND">Land</option>
</select>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select#typeof_dwelling').change(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
     }
 });
</script>
```

How do I make this alert appear with the current option value?

[LIVE CODE](http://7061.a.hostable.me/hkumar/responsive%20wp/?page_id=31)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your code and it will work.  You are missing closing parentheses

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select#typeof_dwelling').change(function () {
        alert($(this).val());
    }); // <-- here
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Py9su/

Comment: Wirey could you look at the live code.  I've updated it.  It's loading from another website.  Perhaps theres the conflict?  Or am i just stupid again...?

Comment: just wondering.  Why are you loading so many jQuery packages?

Comment: Yeah... picking up where someone else left off.  Fixing that now.  Um  would the ajaxness of the form be the conflict of why the alert doesnt show on change?

Comment: No I think there's something else causing the issue.  When looking at the console `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'orbit' /hkumar/responsive%20wp/?page_id=31:79` and 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined easyXDM.min.js:24` shows up as errors

Comment: Interesting.  I've removed the duplicates jquerys & plugins.  This form is generated from reality ninja as an iframe.  could this be the conflict?

Comment: nope.. now try commenting out this code `var socket = new easyXDM.Socket({  });`

Comment: Apparently var socket is coming from modernizr.  I've removed it for now for debugging is it still creating this error? or a new error... endless errors :c

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14650/discussion-between-wirey-and-matthew-harwood)